# Removing classes with jQuery using logical operators

Tags: jquery, css

I've been experimenting and I was wondering if it was possible to remove a class from a div from all divs which are not the one indicated:

```
$(function() {                                                  
    $('#tab-2').click(function() {
        $(!"#tab-1").removeClass("current");
});
```

Essentially, I'm looking for a piece of code that says "remove this class from all divs that are not divs with an id = #tab-1." It needs to be excuted on click and not as a toggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use `.not()` function: http://jsfiddle.net/awzqx50d/.

JS:

```
$("div").not("#tab").removeClass("dark");
```